# Migrated project from eclipse to intelliJ: FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am new with IntelliJ 14 and now I have migrated project from eclipse to intelliJ. My problem is that I'm getting this error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [src/main/java/com/myproject/beans/beans.xml] cannot be opened because
>   it does not exist.

I am sure that beans.xml is in this directory.

```
AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
               "com/myproject/beans/beans.xml");
 context.close();
```

beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
......

</beans>
```

Comment: Maybe some screenshots would help, since we can't examine your file system to ensure you're not making a "similarly-named-directory" error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend moving your Spring XML into a `src/main/resources` directory. This follows convention, then you can simply mark this new directory as a "resources root" by right-clicking it in the project view, and selecting "Mark Directory As..."

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like IntelliJ is not putting your file (or that directory branch) onto the classpath. Try looking in `File | Project Structure | Modules`.

Make sure the directory that holds `com/myproject/beans/beans.xml` is listed on the far right as a `Content Root`. If not, right-click on the directory and add it. Ideally it should be a `Resource Folder`, separate from the `src` folders.